# getElementsByClass and appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid, appendchild

just brushing up on my javascript skills and trying to figure out why getElementsByClass isn't working for my code.  The code is pretty simple.  Upon clicking a button "clicky", the script will create a child h1 element of div.  It works perfectly fine when I use getElementById and changing the div class to Id but doesn't work when I change it to class.

I've tried, getElementsByClassName, getElementsByClass, getElementsByTagName and changing the div to the appropriate attribute but no luck.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>


<body>
<p>Click on button to see how appendChild works</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Clicky </button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
var first = document.createElement("H1");
var text = document.createTextNode("Jason is pretty awesome");
first.appendChild(text);

document.getElementsByName("thistime").appendChild(first);

}
</script>

<div class="thistime">Hi</div>

    </body>






</html>
```

Comment: You're actually using `getElementsByName()`, and `name` is not a valid property of non interactive form elements. Secondly you're working with a NodeList or a collection, over which you have to iterate in order to use `appendChild()` on each element in the collection. And then it wouldn't work as you want because all you'd be doing is inserting the created element into the first element of the collection, then moving it to the second, then the third and so on until it's in the last. So you'd also need to use `cloneNode` or repeatedly create the created element in every iteration of said loop.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to update your code from

```
document.getElementsByName("thistime").appendChild(first);
```

to

```
document.getElementsByClassName("thistime")[0].appendChild(first);
```

For reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Working code - http://plnkr.co/edit/k8ZnPFKYKScn8iYiZQk0?p=preview

Answer (score 13):

You could use [**getElementsByClassName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), which is supported in IE9+:

```
  document.getElementsByClassName("thistime")[0].appendChild(first);
```

But a better alternative may be [**querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryselector), which is supported in IE8+

```
  document.querySelector(".thistime").appendChild(first);
```

Note that `querySelector()` uses CSS selector syntax, so you should place a dot (.) before the class.

**Snippet:**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var first = document.createElement("H1");
  var text = document.createTextNode("Jason is pretty awesome");
  first.appendChild(text);

  document.querySelector(".thistime").appendChild(first);
}
```

```html
<p>Click on button to see how appendChild works</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Clicky</button>

<div class="thistime">Hi</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, querySelector seems a lot more useful, I'll definitely be using it more!

Answer (score 4):

As you have noticed, the function is called `getElementsByName` with "elements" being a plural.

It returns a *list* of markups by their name (and not their css class).

You need to use the function that handles the class name, and get the first element of the array, or loop on all the results, depending on what you are looking for.